# How get access to amd module from next module during define

Tags: requirejs, amd, js-amd

I have this working code.

```
define(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js'],function(axios) { 
    axios.post('/user');
});
```

But I want to use axios inside next module r.js

```
define([
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js',
    'https://example.com/r.js], function(axios) { 
    return r; 
});
```

But axios is undefined.

r.js

```
var r = function () {
  console.log('worked') // worked
  axios.post('/user'); // axios undefined
}
```

Is it possible? I have not access to requre.js config :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is doing now:

- you define a module which has two dependencies, `axios` and `r`,
- requirejs starts downloading both file async
- `r` is regular script (not amd module) and does not have axios as dependency
- if `r` loads first, then you have `axios` undefined
- if `axios` loads first it registers itself as amd module and it is not visible as global, so you have undefined

First solution for your problem is to rewrite `r` as amd module and specify `axios` as its dependency.

Second solution is to specify `axios` as `r`'s dependency via `shim`.